# PHP script that reads external HTML source code and lists the code between the tags

Tags: php, html-parsing

Basically I want to write php code that lists all the contents that are between `<h1>` tags from external url.

I don't want just the first but all of them. So if the source of the external website is

```
<html>
  <title></title>
  <head></head>
  <h1>Test Here</h1>
  <h1>Test here</h1>
</html>
```

I want to make a script that generates only the content between the `<h1>` tags that would be:

```
Test Here
Test here
```

I'm familiar with PHP but I just cant think of scripts that do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is your friend.

```
$dom = file_get_html("http://yourserver.com/path/to/file.html");
// alternatively use str_get_html($html) if you have the html string already...

foreach ($dom->find("h1") as $node)
{
    echo $node->innertext;
}
```

It is very powerful and can do much, much more.

Comment: Yeah i also would recommend using simple_html_dom   because writing regex is more complicated